# How can I slideDown with #states?

Tags: javascript

I have a form using "#states" (in the Relation module), and it works, but it kind of jumps around. A nice slideDown would be so much better.

How can I do that instead of just making it visible?

Comment: I'd love to know this too. It would be nice to easily define the transition, rather than have the form abruptly change when an option is selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on Mike's post, the code above only made the element side down, not back up again.
To get it to slide up and down I added e.stopPropagation(); so the full code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('form.slide').bind('state:visible', function(e) {
        if(e.trigger) {
            $(e.target).closest('.form-item, .form-submit, .form-wrapper')[e.value ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 10):

I assume you're using the visible state?

The code that is responsible for doing this is in states.js:

```
$(document).bind('state:visible', function(e) {
    if (e.trigger) {
      $(e.target).closest('.form-item, .form-submit, .form-wrapper')[e.value ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    }
  });
```

As you can see, it calls show/hide without any configurable parameters, which means that it can't be easily changed.

However, the comment above that block is interesting:

```
/**
 * Global state change handlers. These are bound to "document" to cover all
 * elements whose state changes. Events sent to elements within the page
 * bubble up to these handlers. We use this system so that themes and modules
 * can override these state change handlers for particular parts of a page.
 */
```

If I understand this correctly, you can override the event handler for your specific page element, e.g. the form or even single form elements, by adding something like this:

```
$('form.your-form-class').bind('state:visible', function(e) {
  if (e.trigger) {
    $(e.target).closest('.form-item, .form-submit, .form-wrapper')[e.value ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']();
  }
});
```

I guess you will need to return FALSE to prevent that the event bubbles up further in the DOM tree.

Comment: Worked beautifully!  If you're doing this inline (which I wouldn't recommend) replace `$`'s with `jQuery` and wrap in `drupal_add_js("[Berdir's code here]", array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer'));`

Comment: It would be cool if someone could update this to also work with jquerys new `.on()` instead of `.bind()`.

Comment: You should not react to the document.ready event. You should be using a drupal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Berdir's post, I was able to tweak it and get it working in a custom module.

So in my .module file I added this line under the hook_init() function

```
function er_init(){
    drupal_add_js('custom.js'); 
}
```

Then in the custom.js file,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('form#user-profile-form').bind('state:visible', function(e) {
    if (e.trigger) {
      jQuery(e.target).closest('.form-item, .form-submit, .form-wrapper')[e.value ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut']();
    }
});
```

})

Of course, in this case, it will only apply to the User Profile.