# #states with effects (fade, slide)

Tags: javascript

I'm using the form API #states feature to show and hide fields based on the value of other inputs. This is working great; however, I would like to have the option to fade or slide the inputs as they are shown and hidden.

I realise the conditional fields module offers this functionality, but I found it too buggy to use.

I am using this code.

```php
$form['more_info'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('Additional Information'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => TRUE,

  // Expand the expand_more_info fieldset if the box is checked.
  '#states' => array(
    'expanded' => array(
      ':input[name="expand_more_info"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
    ),
  ),
);
```

This made me think using 'expanded' instead of 'visible' would make the element slide and not just appear however this is not working for me.

I am editing a node form using hook_form_alter so my working code (but with no effect) looks like this.

```php
$form['field_full_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#states'] = array(
    'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="field_person_type[und]"]'=> array(
            array('value' => 'Contractor'),
            array('value' => 'ICM'),
            array('value' => 'Member of public'),
        ),     
    ),
);
```

Replacing visible with expanded or collapsed has no effect so I guess these properties only apply to fieldsets, not elements. A full list of possible states can be [found here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7).

So, is is possible to fade or slide form elements using #states?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11905/how-can-i-slidedown-with-states

Comment: that `expanded` is for fieldset expand/collapse feature.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. may be it will help you.

```
**Your Code:**
$form['more_info'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('Additional Information'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#collapsed' => TRUE,

  // Expand the expand_more_info fieldset if the box is checked.
  '#states' => array(
    'expanded' => array(
      ':input[name="expand_more_info"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Instead of that you can try it in another way which is mentioned below in hook_form_alter() function.

Example:

```
$form['more_info'] = array(
                          '#type' => 'fieldset',
                          '#title' => t('Additional Information'),
                          '#collapsible' => TRUE,
                          '#collapsed' => TRUE,
                     );

**$form['more_info']['und']['#states']**= array(
                                'expanded' => array(
                                 ':input[**name="expand_more_info[und]**"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
                                ),
                             );
```

Note: you can use 'visible' instead of 'expanded'.
you can try this in your custom module or template.php

Answer (score 0):

You miss understand this concept, I think, In your code

```
$form['field_full_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#states'] = array(
    'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="field_person_type[und]"]'=> array(
            array('value' => 'Contractor'),
            array('value' => 'ICM'),
            array('value' => 'Member of public'),
        ),     
    ),
);
```

you have written for,
It means when the field "field_persion_type[und]" value is "Contractor or ICM or Member of public" then only the $form['field_full_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] field will be visible

```
$form['field_persion_type']['und'] = array(
  '#states' = array(
    'expanded' => array(
      // we could set with field id
      // '#id-of-field' => array('checked' => TRUE),
      ':input[name="field_full_name"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
     ),
   ),
);
```

So now if the field_full_name selected the field_persion_type field will be expand..

Comment: Yes, I understand. `field_person_type` is a series of radio buttons. If the value is `Contractor` or `ICM` or `Member of public` then the `field_full_name` will be visible. My question concerns how to animate the field appearing / disappearing.